# Is it possible to modify the bytecode and save it with javassist?

Tags: java, bytecode-manipulation, javassist

All the references I've found on the web says the bytecode can be modified at runtime, but I don't seem to find if that modified bytecode could replace the original.

This way the original bytecode could be substituted once, and the rest of the time, use the enhanced afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called `build-time` byte-code instrumentation; `javassist` as well as libraries such as `aspectj` supports this model.

I've had good experience with the latter in combination with `Apache Maven` using the [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/weaveJars.html).

**[Edit]** Also see the [Implementing Build-time Bytecode Instrumentation With Javassist](http://java.dzone.com/articles/implementing-build-time) article.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Thanks. Looks like it is possible, trying right now!

Comment: If anyone want to see the sample ( in spanish ) here's the link: http://www.javamexico.org/blogs/oscarryz/nano_ejemplo_de_javassist Just look at the code, is self explaining